# Users getting to wrong sharepoint application

Tags: 2010, redirect

I have 2 versions of the same Sharepoint application, one is a development version and one is the live production version.

I have had a couple of people somehow manage to get onto the dev version by accident.

Is there a way I can:

1. find any unwanted references to the dev system in the live system content?
2. automatically redirect all users except developers to the live system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't believe there is any out of the box way to do this.
2. You could potentially write a custom control that you put onto the development web application's master page that checks for membership of a certain SPGroup or other logic of your choice and redirect to the production version of the page requested if they aren't part of the group.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider using User policies under Web Application management (via the Central Administration), provided that you have at least one Group to differentiate the Developers. Set to "No Access" for the Group of Developers forbidding them access to whatever Site Collection is hosted on that Web Application.

For the redirection, they shall fall on the Access Denied page automatically, if that is an important part, you could change that page to include another link (http://geekswithblogs.net/JayantSharma/archive/2012/07/09/how-to-change-system-application-pages.aspx)